# react-native expo cli - eas homescreen widget

Tags: android, react-native, expo, widget, eas

ı making react-native app with using expo-cli. `npx create-expo-app my-app`
can ı make android widget with expo-cli ?

when ı search tuttorials they are usign bare reactnative. and in one article said " you have to use bare react native " but in one reddit post said " with new eas updates you can use expo for making widget "

or should ı use bare react native ?
if ı use bare react native , can ı use eas for deploying and updating my app to play store ?

Answer (score 8):

You might find [this repo](https://github.com/gaishimo/eas-widget-example) helpful, especially the `widget` and `plugin` folders.

Sorry for short answers. I do not have enough reputations to comment.

Comment: hope you will get some reputation with my upvote and comments :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make android widgets with Expo without writing native code by using https://github.com/sAleksovski/react-native-android-widget

You cannot use Expo Go, and will need to build an ["Expo Dev Client"](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/introduction/) for development.

Other than that, deploying/updating the app on App Store should be the same.